# why is 'max-height: 0' failing to completely hide my div?

Tags: html, css, height, hide

I have searched thoroughly for a solution however have had no luck. I have a responsive nav with a ul I am trying to hide using `max-height: 0`, basic stuff. It works when the div has no border around it, however when I add a border to it, the bottom and top borders show (as if the UL is closed).

Here is the markup:

```
   <nav id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li id="li_1" ><a href="#">text</a><img class="li-ico" src="" alt="" /></li>
        <li id="li_2" ><a href="#">text</a><img class="li-ico" src="" alt="" /></li>
        <li id="li_3" ><a href="#">text</a><img class="li-ico" src="" alt="" /></li>
        <li id="li_4" ><a href="#">text</a><img class="li-ico" src="" alt="" /></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

and css:

```
#menu {
 right: 0;
 top: 100%;
 line-height: 30px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 border:1px solid red;
 border-radius:3px;
 max-height: 0;
 opacity: 1;

 -webkit-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in-out;
 transition: max-height 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

like I stated, when I remove the border, div is hidden just fine, but with border it isn't.. suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

why are u trying to hide it using max-height?

if u want to hide it completely do

```
#menu {
   display: none;
}
```

if you must have a border try using

```
#menu {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

borderbox puts the border on the inside of the div instead of the outside.

Comment: how can i hide it using min height

Comment: sorry i messed up, forget the min height thing